# Use one column to cover another column and adopt another column value when NA

Tags: r

My system is R 3.5.1 with Rstudio 1.1.463

There are 2 columns, `cola` and `colb` in my dataframe `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(
    cola = c("A","C",NA,"C"),
    colb = c("C",NA,"C","D"))
```

`df` is as shown below:

```
cola   colb
A        C
C        NA
NA       C
C        D
```

I want to use `colb` to cover `cola` when `colb` is not `NA`,adopt `cola` when `colb` is `NA`.

The expected result is as shown below:

```
cola   colb   
C        C       
C        NA     
C        C      
D        D
```

How to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`. The `mutate_all` is done since the sample data has factors.:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  mutate(cola=ifelse(is.na(colb),cola,colb))
```

Result:

```
  cola colb
1    C    C
2    C <NA>
3    C    C
4    D    D
```

Comment: `could not find function "%>%"` when I run this answer.

Comment: `install.packages("dplyr")`;`library(dplyr)` then run the code.

Comment: when cannot use `%>%`,is there anything wrong with my answer?

Comment: @kittygirl It's just preference and convenience. It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

`coalesce` function from `dplyr` package can be useful here:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(cola = coalesce(colb, cola))
```

output:

```
  cola colb
1    C    C
2    C <NA>
3    C    C
4    D    D
```

Comment: `could not find function "%>%"` when I run this answer.

Answer (score 0):

We could replace values in `cola` when `colb` is not `NA`.

```
df$cola[!is.na(df$colb)] <- df$colb[!is.na(df$colb)]

#  cola colb
#1    C    C
#2    C <NA>
#3    C    C
#4    D    D
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(
 cola = c("A","C",NA,"C"),
 colb = c("C",NA,"C","D"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @kittygirl yes, you need to keep them as characters otherwise t will not be able to assign values with `factors` of different levels.

Comment: how about my answer, pls give me comment.

Answer (score 0):

I provide solution as below:
should convert `factor` column to `character` column first
`df$cola<-ifelse(is.na(df$colb),df$cola,df$colb)`

Otherwise,use `df<-mutate(df,cola = coalesce(colb, cola))`

Comment: this is functionally the same as the other answers, so yes - it's fine.

Comment: If you copy your `df` and apply this function then you will get output as 1, 2, 1, 2 in `cola` and not characters since the columns are factors.